# How to change password requirements?

Tags: 14.04, password, passphrase

I tried to change my Ubuntu password but it keeps saying my new password is not "Good Enough" even when it passes my company security requirements:

- At least 8 characrters
- At least one number
- At least one uppercase letter

[image: password]

I know, I could use better, stronger and nicer password, but, I want my Ubuntu follow the requirements from my company. How can I force Ubuntu to let me change my password?

Comment: Try it from an Terminal, simply run `passwd`

Comment: thanks! That worked! But still I keep wondering why it does not work the same by GUI...

Comment: The gui includes a rather strict password check, while via command line, you can decide if it is save enough or not.

Comment: Ran into this too on 14.04 when I tried adding a user. Must be a bug. I found the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1318199 however it hasn't received much attention yet.

Comment: On ubuntu 14.04.2 the passwd command is not without its own idea of what's too simple, similar to previous passwords etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try `sudo passwd [login]`

See also https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/user-management.html

Comment: Definitely faster way to deal with this password sec issue!

Comment: Yes, this works, but it has a disadvantage. Because it doesn't go through the desktop APIs, it makes Chrome, in particular, forget all of your stored passwords.